# How to do automated accessibility testing using Selenium-Java?

Tags: java, selenium, accessibility, deque, lighthouse

I need to integrate Accessibility testing into my existing Selenium-Java framework. What tools can be used for accessibility testing in Selenium and Java?
My requirements:

1. Tool should be compatible with the Selenium-Java framework.
2. Need to run it on the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Hi, please see the following site: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/accessibility-testing-with-selenium/

It is for c# but can easily be applied to Java

Answer (score 0):

To run web accessibility tests in Java projects with Selenium, You can use the **Deque axe-core Selenium API**

**You can check my medium blog for detail:**

https://medium.com/geekculture/accessibility-automation-testing-using-deque-axe-core-seleniumapi-c3e63a98575a

Selenium integration enables testing of full pages and sites.

**Maven Dependency:**

```
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.deque.html.axe-core/selenium →
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.deque.html.axe-core</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
 <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Sample Code:**

```
public static void checkAccessibility() {

    AxeRunOnlyOptions runOnlyOptions = new AxeRunOnlyOptions();
    runOnlyOptions.setType("tag");
    runOnlyOptions.setValues(Arrays.asList("wcag2a", "wcag2aa"));

    AxeRunOptions options = new AxeRunOptions();
    options.setRunOnly(runOnlyOptions);

    AxeBuilder axe = new AxeBuilder().withOptions(options);
    //Pass WebDriver Object
    Results result = axe.analyze(getWebDriver());
    List<Rule> violationList = result.getViolations();
    System.out.println("Violation list size :"+result.getViolations().size());
    for (Rule r : result.getViolations()) {
        System.out.println("Complete = "+r.toString());
        System.out.println("Tags = "+r.getTags());
        System.out.println("Description = "+r.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Help Url = "+r.getHelpUrl());
    }

    System.out.println("Inapplicable list size :"+result.getInapplicable().size());
    for (Rule r : result.getInapplicable()) {
        System.out.println("Complete = "+r.toString());
        System.out.println("Tags = "+r.getTags());
        System.out.println("Description = "+r.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Help Url = "+r.getHelpUrl());
    }
}

private static WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, working example using Selenium `4.8.1` and Axe-core `4.6.0`

```java
import com.deque.html.axecore.results.Results;
import com.deque.html.axecore.results.Rule;
import com.deque.html.axecore.selenium.AxeBuilder;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

        @Test
    public void accessibilityTest() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments(
                "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("wcag21aa");
        AxeBuilder builder = new AxeBuilder();
        builder.withTags(tags);
        Results results = builder.analyze(driver);
        List<Rule> violations = results.getViolations();
        for (Rule i : violations) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(0, results.getViolations().size());
    }
```

[The repository for this code](https://github.com/ultimate-qa/java-sdet)